# Django migration between branches releases

Tags: django, database, migration, branch, hotfix

We are to start branching our master code in the first stable version, and the company has to maintain 2 feature releases.
To manage the migrations we use the django migration, but what we don't know is how to load with the hotfix scripts that we could have in the feature releases and master too.

I used to use flyway witch let you run the migration with out of order, so if you had in you branch the versions **[001, 002, 003, 006]**, and master **[001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007]**, where 006 was a hotfix replicated in both, when you migrate to the next version from master the 006 will be skipped.

I need a solution like this or a workflow that solve it in django. I couldn't find it.

Thank you